# Почему не работает HTTP сервер prometheus?

Tags: python, django, prometheus

Имеется приложение Django, в котором необходимо собирать метрики с помощью prometheus.

Используется библиотека django_prometheus:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'django_prometheus',
   ...
]
 
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_prometheus.middleware.PrometheusBeforeMiddleware',
    ...
    'django_prometheus.middleware.PrometheusAfterMiddleware',
]
```

Если я добавлю в urlpatterns ручку "/metrics", то все работает нормально:

```
urlpatterns += [
    path('', include('django_prometheus.urls')),
]
```

На `localhost:8000/metrics` отображаются корректные метрики.

Но мне необходимо запустить сервер на отдельном порту, который будет возвращать метрики.

Сервер запускается с помощью функции prometheus_client.start_http_server(port). Также можно использовать функцию из пакета django_prometheus. Я добавил следующий код в wsgi.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django_prometheus.exports import SetupPrometheusEndpointOnPort
 
SetupPrometheusEndpointOnPort(9090)  # prometheus_client.start_http_server(9090)
```

Это запускает локальный сервер `localhost:9090`, но он возвращает некорректные метрики (все нули).

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Сервер запускается на `8000`, а сбор метрик хотите получить с `9090`? А зачем разделять?

Comment: @gil9red, ну вот так захотели (не я) для однообразия

Comment: @gil9red, я делал подобное с FastAPI и все корректно работает. Т.е. через ручку `/metrics` для FastApi приложения и через запущенный сервер я получал одинаковый результат